# ASP.NET MVC 3 validation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have 2 or more forms with different one hidden value like:

```
    <div class="comment-body">
        <% using (Html.BeginForm(Model.ActionName, "Home", Model.RouteValues, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormAddComment", name = "FormAddComment" }))
           { %>
        <% = Html.ValidationSummary(false) %>
        <fieldset>
            <% if (Model.CommentParentID != null)
               {
                   htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Add a reply...", id = "Comment" };
                   postButtonTitle = "Post Reply";
            %>
            <input type="hidden" name="CommentParentID" id="CommentParentID" value="<% = Model.CommentParentID.ToString() %>" />
            <%} %>
            <% = Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes)%>
            <% = Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Comment) %>
            <input type="submit" value="<% = postButtonTitle %>" class="small blue awesome noborder"
                border="0" />
            <% if (Model.CommentParentID != null)
               {%>
            <a class="hide-sub-comment" href="javascript:void(0);">Cancel</a>
            <%} %>
        </fieldset>
        <%} %>
    </div>
```

Problem is when I try to validate entered value I got the validator message twice. When I add text and click "post" again - one validator is hidden, but page is not valid yet. Why and how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modifying answer since you changed the question.

You could do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $("#NotHiddenComment").change(function () {
            var temp = $("#NotHiddenComment").val();
            $("#HiddenCommentID").text(temp);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will make sure both fields have the same value so you do not get validation errors.

Comment: it could not help. Just show only one error message instead of twice

Comment: above you said it is showing the message twice and now you say it is only showing one error message... I thought that is what you wanted. Check out the article I linked that should offer some valuable insight.

Comment: sorry, I was incorrect. Modified question. Problem is the page is not valid with 2 forms

Comment: I would check your controller and see what is getting posted with each form submission. It is possible the field is only getting sent over with one post. If that is the case you can use javascript to copy the contents from one form to the other so it always gets posted.

Comment: changed my answer to reflect the question change. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Seems problem is not in 2 or more forms. Have problems with only one form. I created new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368030/asp-net-mvc-validation-problem-data-is-not-posted . In any case, thank you for your help